# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'pop' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, tkinter, background

Full text error console

```
Exception in thread Thread-3 (make_jenya):
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1009, in 
_bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 946, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\biron\main.py", line 26, in make_jenya
pop = Toplevel(pop)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'pop' referenced before assignment
```

I want to have an image in the background, but it is not displayed and gives an error.
I know that this topic has been discussed many times, but I still can not understand what the problem is.

Tell me, I'll be glad

==============================================================

My code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from threading import Thread
from playsound import playsound
import webbrowser

root = Tk()

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/'

def OpenUrl(url):
    webbrowser.open_new(url)

def video():
    Thread(target = lambda: OpenUrl(url), daemon=True).start()

def music():
    playsound(r"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\biron\horror_music.mp3")

def sound_clicked_btn():
    playsound(r"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\biron\btn_click.mp3")

def make_jenya():

    pop = Toplevel(pop)
    pop.title("SUPERJENYA.EXE KILLER")
    c=Canvas(pop,bg="gray16", height=200,width=200)
    pop.geometry("500x350")
    pop.resizable(height = False, width=False)

    filename=PhotoImage(file="C://Users//Admin//Desktop//biron//jenya.png")
    background_label=Label(pop,image=filename)
    background_label.place(x=0,y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

    c.pack()




def btn_click():
   if messagebox.askyesno("ЕВГЕНИЙ.EXE", "Вы уверены?") == True:
    Thread(target = sound_clicked_btn, daemon=True).start()
    Thread(target = make_jenya, daemon=True).start()

root['bg']='#fafafa'
root.geometry('300x250')
root.title('Евгений супер мозг')
root.resizable(height = False, width=False)
root.iconphoto(True, PhotoImage(file=('jenya.png')))
Thread(target = music, daemon=True).start()

canvas = Canvas(root, height=300, width=250)

canvas.pack()

frame = Frame(root, bg='red')
frame.place(relx=0.15, rely=0.15, relwidth=0.7, relheight=0.7)
title = Label(frame,text='Увидеть СуперЖеню?', bg='gray', font=40)
title.pack()
btn = Button(frame, text='Да, хочу его увидеть', bg='yellow', height=5, width=8, command=btn_click)
btn.pack()

btn_video = Button(frame, text='Посмотреть видео \n"Суперженя уже не бог"?', bg='blue', height=2, width=25, command=video)
btn_video.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `pop = Toplevel(pop)` you can't assign the toplevel itself as the master parameter. You could either use another toplevel or the root window as master. Note that if you don't define any master the root window is set by default. So the easiest way to solve your case is to leave it empty like `pop = Toplevel()`

Comment: pop do you mean root? Or replace root with pop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is simple, you must define a value to the variable pop. Here is a simpler example of what you are trying to do:

```
x = int(x)
```

This will error as well because x has no value and you cant pass `None` type to `int` function.

To fix your code just define a value for `pop`

Answer (score 1):

The error message:

```
pop = Toplevel(pop)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'pop' referenced before assignment
```

is saying that this `pop` doesn't have a value (has not been assigned to yet):

```
pop = Toplevel(pop)
               ^^^
```